# Python, "you don't have permission to access that port"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python, django

I'm setting up my first Django project on a server

When I do `python manage.py runserver .0.0.0.0:80`, it tells me

`You don't have permission to access that port`.

When I do `python manage.py runserver .0.0.0.0:8000` it tells me that the port is already in use.

I'm trying to run a LAMP stack.

How do I "get permission"? How do I see which processes have ports open?

Comment: I'm trying to get my account unblocked so that I can add questions again, and this question is weighing my ban down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ports lower than 1024 require privileges. `sudo python manage.py runserver .0.0.0.0:80` should do the trick... but if you've got a LAMP stack running on port 80 they won't be able to coexist.

`sudo netstat -nlp` will tell you what processes have which ports open. It should reveal what's on 8080 already.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say that I want to replace what's previously on my LAMP with this django project. How would I go about doing that? It looks like `mysqld` is on `:::80`, if that's the same as `0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: MySQL's listening on port 80? That's a very odd setup if true. Since you're running on AWS, it might be best to start with a fresh instance and install Python/Django from scratch there, so you don't have LAMP cruft.

Comment: Aww man. This was my first server, and I'm so proud of it... I'd rather not abort it in it's third trimester. I'm not used to being a sysadmin, so I guess if this is what happens, I'll get used to it.

Comment: You may want to consider using something like Ansible to build repeatable server setups. It's very handy.